# Outlook 2003 vs. Outlook live - external POP3 emails

Tags: windows-10, email, microsoft-outlook, windows-live-mail

I'm trying to configure an external POP3/SMTP account on both of these apps. I have all of the details needed: email address, username, password, POP3 server and port, SMTP server and port.

on Outlook 2003 - everything works, I got all of my inbox (since January, when I last used it), and I can send emails.

However, when configuring the same account on the free outlook.live.com (via 'Connected accounts'), or even on the Windows 10 embedded Mail app, only outgoing email works - but no email (recent or old) has been retrieved into the inbox.

Edit: it turns out any new email being sent to this POP3 account is received, but I can't see any of my old inbox email, between January and yesterday. Outlook 2003 have retrieved them all, but how can I see those emails in Outlook Live/Win10 Mail?

Comment: You need to look up IMAP settings. POP3 downloads all the messages to the client you've configured it on. Once the messages have been downloaded they are no longer available on the server and another client can't access them. IMAP leaves messages on the servers and syncronizes them with clients.

Comment: So if there are no IMAP settings (for this provider), I should only use a single client in order to see all my old emails?

Answer (score 0):

The answer can be found here:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Read-POP3-email-messages-on-multiple-computers-cf375a53-a3df-47c8-b3b6-17f6139bd9d1

Simply, set the first client (the one which you downloaded all your old emails to)
to "Leave a copy of messages on the server".

Comment: The downside of this is that you usually MUST have one client downloading all the messages. If Client A does not download the messages and Client B does, and A isn't connected to the server all the time and downloading updated messages very frequently, Client A is likely to end up missing messages.